# Stop from automatically connecting to a WiFi network

Tags: wifi, printing

I have just bought a printer that works via its own WiFi connection, so every time I have to print something, I have to manually switch from my usual internet WiFi connection to the printer's. The issue is: though my internet WiFi is preferred in the settings, usually when my computer wakes up it connects to the printer's (I'm not sure why). Is there any way I can let my computer memorize the printer's WiFi password but never automatically connect to it?

Comment: Normally if you set the WiFi ORDER (in the advanced tab) that should do it.